# Select a language in the Google search API

Tags: vb.net, google-api

I am using the google search API to try and fetch some results from google and store them in a listbox.
This is working fine however I want to search in my own language (dutch) instead of the default language (english).

I tried using "dutch", "nl", "nl-NL", language.dutch but it doesn't seem to work, I've also searched alot but couldn't find the right answer.

```
  Dim cl As New GwebSearchClient("www.google.nl")


        Dim rtnList As IList(Of IWebResult) = cl.Search(KEYWORD, LENGTH, LANGUAGE)

        For Each itm As IWebResult In rtnList
            ListBox1.Items.Add(itm.Url) '
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, no experience with this API at all, but maybe this is some information for you:

```
Specific UI language - if you want to specify the language for the UI components (SearchControl, branding, etc...) instead of having it auto-detected then set "language" to the specific language code such as: en, es, zh-CN, pt-PT, and etc...

google.load("search", "1", {"language" : "en"});
```

From [here](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/).